# ¿Cómo buscar una regexp en Teradata?

Tags: sql, regex, teradata

Buenas,
Estoy intentando obtener una expresión regular utilizando la función REGEXP_SUBSTR en Terdata, sin embargo quiero obtener como resultado únicamente una parte de la misma.

Tengo una base con una columna que tiene valores con la siguiente forma:

COLUMNA

> 'texto1#1234' 'texto2#5678' 'texto3#91011' 'texto4#121314' 'texto5#151617'
>   'texto6#18'

y quiero obtener únicamente los dígitos:

RESULTADO

> 1234 5678 91011 121314 151617 18

Al aplicar la función 
`REGEXP_SUBSTR(COLUMNA, '#([0-9]{7,12})$')` obtengo lo siguiente:

RESULTADO

> '#1234'
>   '#5678'
>   '#91011'
>   '#121314'
>   '#151617'
>   '#18'

¿Cómo hago para obtener los resultados sin el "#" utilizando la misma función `REGEXP_SUBSTR`?

Comment: No se si estara bien recomendarte algo sin saber, pero has intentado quitar el simbolo #?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No entendí bien tu pregunta, primero ejemplificas lo que deseas con una cosa y después ejemplificas otra cosa con otro ejemplo, pero va, intentemos resolver los dos.

En el primer ejemplo, tienes esto:

> 'texto1#1234' 'texto2#5678' 'texto3#91011' 'texto4#121314' 'texto5#151617' 'texto6#18'

Y según lo que pides, deseas **SOLO LOS NÚMEROS**, ok obtengamos la expresión regular.

```
'\w+#(\d+)'
```

Donde el token `\w+` espera cualquier palabra con el mínimo de 1 de longitud, seguido de la literal `#` que espera eso; una literal # y por último el grupo de captura (que es lo que deseas) donde el token `\d+` espera un dígito con el mínimo de 1 de longitud.

Ahora bien, probémoslo en algún analizador de [**expresiones regulares**](https://regex101.com/r/fF3yB2/1).

Efectivamente, el resultado que deseas, es el que se muestra, capturando únicamente los valores numéricos después de la literal #.

Si no te funciona ese código es porque el sistema donde lo deseas probar no tiene definidos los tokens como `\d` o `\w`, en dado caso te recomendaría usar el siguiente.

```
'[a-zA-Z0-9]+#([0-9]+)'
```

Que básicamente es “lo mismo a lo que deseas” pero aquí en la clase `[a-zA-Z0-9]` solo acepta literales o dígitos, mientras que en el token `\w` puede aceptar caracteres especiales como el `_`. De igual manera, te dejo el [**link**](https://regex101.com/r/fF3yB2/2) para que puedas probarlo.

Ahora, para el segundo ejemplo, donde tenemos una entrada cómo esta:

> '#1234' '#5678' '#91011' '#121314' '#151617' '#18'

Y el resultado que deseas es el siguiente:

> '#1234' '#5678' '#91011' '#121314' '#151617' '#18'

Sin la literal #, bueno para ello utilizaríamos la siguiente expresión.

```
'#([0-9]+)'
```

De igual manera, puedes insertar la expresión regular y probarla para verificar que si funciona.

No sé si esto era realmente lo que buscabas, saludos.

Answer (score 1):

Prueba con:

```sql
REGEXP_SUBSTR(COLUMNA, '[0-9]+', 1, 2, 'i')
```

donde, de acuerdo con [*Regular Expression Functions*](http://www.teradatawiki.net/2014/05/regular-expression-functions.html):

- `COLUMNA`, el texto donde la función buscará,
- `'[0-9]+'`, la expresión regular que la función usará para la búsqueda,
- `1`, comenzando desde la primera posición en el texto,
- `2`, encontrando la segunda ocurrencia,
- `'i'`, sin importar si son mayúsculas o minúsculas.